# How to invoke render for JSON

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to render a JSON response.

This works:

```
render json: @user
```

and so does this

```
render :json => @user
```

This does *not* work:

```
render { json: @user }
```

Since this is a valid hash, my understanding is that this should also work.

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to interpret the hash as a block. (In other words, this is just how Ruby parses.)

You'd need to add the parens in order to get this to work, although then you wouldn't need the curly braces.